# Shift+Arrow not working to change Windows in tmux

Tags: windows, tmux

I tried to bind Shift+left / Shift+Right to change Windows on tmux and it just wont work. When I do alt+arrow it works perfectly. Tried with

```
bind -n S-left  prev
bind -n S-right next
```

and with

```
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window
```

and neither of them work.
However,

```
bind-key -n M-Right next-window
bind-key -n M-Left previous-window
```

work perfectly.
Im using Konsole on Debian. Here's my .tmux.conf

```
# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-Space
bind-key C-Space send-prefix
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g mouse on
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm-color256:smcup@:rmcup@"
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the binding was already used in konsole, as soon as I changed it from konsole it started working on tmux.